# Can't export database via SQL in Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to export database to file(via SQL) but Android Studio(Giraffe | 2022.3.1) shows me error.
`Issue while downloading database(dbName): Can't open offline databse data/data/path_to_database`  
Tried to export via CSV, and it's worked.

Comment: facing the same issue, you can try another way to get access to db. 
Goto "Device explorer" tab, then "data/data/path_to_database" to download database_name.db file